# Swift - Rest Api Progress

Tags: swift, api, resources, request, alamofire

i have a basic API on serverside, which is requested by my Swift-App.

For now i can load the resources from the API and display the data:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class RestApiManager {

    var resources: JSON = [

        "resources": [

            "articles": [],

            "categories": []

        ],

    ]

    let apiUrl: String
    let apiUsername: String
    let apiPassword: String

    var resourceToBeCalled: String = ""

    init(apiUrl: String, apiUsername: String, apiPassword: String) {

        self.apiUrl = apiUrl
        self.apiUsername = apiUsername
        self.apiPassword = apiPassword

        requestArticleResource()
        requestCategegoryResource()

    }

    // Article Resource
    func requestArticleResource() {

        self.resourceToBeCalled = "articles"

        getArticleResource() { responseObject, error in

            let articleResource = JSON(responseObject!)

            self.resources["resources"]["articles"] = articleResource

        }

    }

    func getArticleResource(completion: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

        collectDataFromApi() { responseObject, error in

            completion(responseObject: responseObject, error: error)

        }

    }

    // Category Resource
    func requestCategegoryResource() {

        self.resourceToBeCalled = "categories"

        getCategoryResorce() { responseObject, error in

            let categoryResource = JSON(responseObject!)

            self.resources["resources"]["categories"] = categoryResource

        }

    }

    func getCategoryResorce(completion: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

        collectDataFromApi() { responseObject, error in

            completion(responseObject: responseObject, error: error)

        }

    }

    // COLLECT DATA METHOD
    func collectDataFromApi(completionHandler: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

        prepareHttpRequest(completionHandler)

    }

    // PREPARE HTTP REQUEST METHOD
    func prepareHttpRequest(completionHandler: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

        let alamofireRequest = Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(self.apiUrl)" + "/api/" + "\(self.resourceToBeCalled)")

        alamofireRequest.authenticate(user: self.apiUsername, password: self.apiPassword)

        alamofireRequest.responseJSON { request, response, responseObject, error in

            completionHandler(responseObject: responseObject as? NSDictionary, error: error)

        }

    }

    func getData() -> JSON {

        return self.resources

    }

}
```

This is my RestApiManager.

In my TableViewController this Manager is called to retrieve the data:

```
var result: JSON = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var restApiManager = RestApiManager(apiUrl: "http://example.com", apiUsername: "test", apiPassword: "test")

    let seconds = 10.0
    let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    var dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        self.result = restApiManager.getData()

    })
}
```

In this TableViewController i just created an instance of the class(RestApiManager) and waited 10 seconds to let the data load from the API.

This is quite dirty.

Thats why i wanted to include a progress-bar to the display the progress in the TableView, i already know how a progress-bar works and i already visited the progress-method of Alamofire, but i am not sure if its even possible to include this progress-bar in my existing app-structure.

If anyone could share his knowledge, would be great.

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: why dont you use a simple loader or `activityIndicator`?

Comment: thanks for answer, but how to show activityIndicator as long as data is loading?

Comment: You can perform something like : show activity indicator when you make a request(or call a function) and hide it when you get some response.

Comment: The request is asynchronous, thats why i need the progress..